# How to draw a closed curve in cartesian coordinates based on its area

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I've posted a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3948038/solving-an-integral-which-results-in-elliptic-integrals-without-never-having-hea) before asking how I would derive the length of a closed curve that I found in a paper. I am returning to now ask how I could draw my shape in Cartesian coordinates. From my [first post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3941239/integral-of-the-min-between-sec-and-csc/3941264#3941264) about this paper we have that the authors use a particular case o the Gielis formula where, in polar coordinates, $\rho$ is defined as such:

$$
\begin{align}
\rho = r_m(\varphi) 
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(|\cos{\frac{m\varphi}{4}|^n}+|\sin{\frac{m\varphi}{4}}|^n\right)^{-\frac{1}{n}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\min{\left(\left|\sec{\frac{m\varphi}{4}}\right|,\left|\csc{\frac{m\varphi}{4}}\right|\right)}\label{1}
\tag{1}\end{align}$$

where m is a positive integer that defines the number of pseudovertices of a closed curve $C_m$. They then show that from the closed curve equations we have that

$$A_m = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi} r_m^2(\varphi) \,d\varphi = 1 \tag{2}$$

$$
\begin{align}
l_m &=  \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{r_m^2(\varphi)+\left[\frac{dr_m(\varphi)}{d\varphi}\right]^2} \,d\varphi \\
&= \sqrt{8+\frac{m^2}{2}}+4\left[F\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\bigg|1-\frac{m^2}{16}\right)-E\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\bigg|1-\frac{m^2}{16}\right)\right] \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

What I did then was stard from a square and define the area I want to have on my practical implementation (which is why I need to know how to draw the curves with respect to m). My square 2mm x 2mm, so my $A_m = 4~mm^2$. So now how would I proceed to create my geometry on a Cartesian framework?

I am sorry if this sounds a bit stupid, I've never attempted anything remotely close to this. Thank you in advance

Comment: You say "My square is 2mm by 2mm, so my $A_m$ is 4 mm^2."  What are you trying to do here?  If you're trying to fit this curve inside of a square, like to cut it out of a square, you're going to need the area to be considerably less than the area of the square.  Trying to make the area inside the curve by 4mm^2 only makes sense if you're (1) trying to cut it out of a larger thing and have the resulting thing weigh the same as a square, or (2) you're going to melt down your square or something and re-form it into this shape.

Comment: Hi Daniel, this is the figure from the article: https://imgur.com/a/fdKvW4C. I might not have said what I intend correctly. In the case of the article they use $A_m = 1$ the equation. This show that a closed curve using the particular case in (1) maintains a unitary area but can increase its length by changing m. The square is the case where $m=4$. I decided to then start by using the square and find the area I intend to use with respect of electromagnetic performance that I want. Now I want to maintain the same area and increase the $m$ as it looks like they did in their paper

Comment: As $n\to \infty$ the fractal Koch curve.has infinite perimeter enclosing a finite area. Is it so here also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x = \rho \cos (\varphi)$ and $y = \rho \sin (\varphi)$ we can just plug your expression

$$\rho(\varphi) = \frac{1}{2} \min\left(\left|\sec \frac{m \varphi}{4}\right|, \left|\csc \frac{m \varphi}{4}\right|\right)$$

in, giving the Cartesian parametrization

$$x(t) = \frac{1}{2} \min\left(\left|\sec \frac{m t}{4}\right|, \left|\csc \frac{m t}{4}\right|\right) \cos(t)$$
$$y(t) = \frac{1}{2} \min\left(\left|\sec \frac{m t}{4}\right|, \left|\csc \frac{m t}{4}\right|\right) \sin(t)$$

---

Update: in MATLAB (actually, GNU Octave),

```
m = 5;
t = 0:0.01:2*pi;
x = min(abs(sec(m * t / 4)), abs(csc(m * t / 4))) .* cos(t) / 2;
y = min(abs(sec(m * t / 4)), abs(csc(m * t / 4))) .* sin(t) / 2;
plot(x, y)
```

[image: plot of these equations for m = 5]

Comment: Hi, Daniel. That's the correct answer, and I was (hopefully) a bit burnt out on the subject. The main issue is generating this shape in the Cartesian coordinates (i.e: using a tool such as python/matlab to plot it). I am using matlab for this, my [code](https://pastebin.com/pBQdRZqQ) is here. 

I've set two plots with _t_ going from 0 to $\frac{2\pi}{m}$ and 0 to $2\pi$ (the second being incorrect). Yet my plot for the first interval seems to present a single [vertice](https://imgur.com/a/bd0H1M4).

Comment: @GuilhermeTheis: You left out the absolute values around the secant and cosecant in your code.

Comment: Oh god this whole thing makes me feel so stupid. Thank you and sorry for the trouble